# Imprimir palabras contenidas en arbol binario

Tags: java, recursión, árboles-binarios

Partiendo del siguiente árbol binario debo imprimir por pantalla las palabras que pueda contener, con un salto de linea entre ellas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He obtenido funciones como la de recorrer todos los nodos para sumar su contenido o simplemente contar los nodos, pero no llego a comprender como imprimir cada palabra empezando siempre con la raíz principal (letra B) y reutilizando letras

Función número de nodos:

```
public static int numNodos(Arbol a) {
    if (a.esVacio()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + numNodos(a.hijoIzq) + numNodos(a.hijoDcho());
    }
}
```

Función profundidad del árbol:

```
public static int profundidad(Arbol a, int maxprof) {
    if (a.esVacio()) {
        return maxprof;
    } else {
        return Math.Max(profundidad(a.hijoIzq(), maxprof + 1), profundidad(a.hijoDcho(), maxprof + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes Ayudarme con el codigo completo para analizarlo?